# Dynamic Insert Loop

Tags: sql-server

As I understand it, the following code:

```
declare @csvnmbr nvarchar(3)
declare @sql nvarchar(400)
set @csvnmbr = 1
set @sql = 'BULK INSERT #tablename FROM ''C:\TEMP\'+@csvnmbr+'.csv''
            WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '','')'
while @csvnmbr < 4
begin
print @sql
set @csvnmbr = @csvnmbr + 1
end
GO
```

Should print:

```
BULK INSERT #tablename FROM 'C:\TEMP\1.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')

BULK INSERT #tablename FROM 'C:\TEMP\2.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')

BULK INSERT #tablename FROM 'C:\TEMP\3.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')
```

but it doesn't, it prints:

```
BULK INSERT #tablename FROM 'C:\TEMP\1.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')

BULK INSERT #tablename FROM 'C:\TEMP\1.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')

BULK INSERT #tablename FROM 'C:\TEMP\1.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')
```

Does anyone know why the loop won't print the number sequence but just sticks to the first csv number instead?

If I do this though:

```
declare @csvnmbr nvarchar(3)
declare @sql nvarchar(400)
set @csvnmbr = 1
set @sql = 'HI'
while @csvnmbr < 4
begin
print @sql
print @csvnmbr
set @csvnmbr = @csvnmbr + 1
end
GO
```

There is no apparent need to write the @sql inside the loop. Any idea why the fact that the @sql statement is dynamic means it needs to be reset each time?

Comment: All the answers certainly make the loop work. Thanks for that, I have edited the question above to see if we can establish the reasoning behind it, please see above, thanks again.

Comment: it is because when you do `set @sql = 'BULK INSERT #tablename FROM ''C:\TEMP\'+@csvnmbr+'.csv''
            WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '','')'` the value of @csvmbrn is replaced by actual value. So @sql is fixed there. You want something like reference to @csvmbrn though. In your second example you have 2 prints not one.

Comment: ...so, printing (or executing) the sql variable sets the sql variable and it has to be reset back to csvnmbr variable to receive the new value of csvnmbr variable. I think the reason for not understanding it was that I didn't realise the sql variable would be SET by printing (or executing it), I thought it was just referencing the csvnmbr variable. Thanks Lad2025. I saw your 'Passing String by Reference' code below, understood.

Comment: No printing  or executing does not SET, your example above show 'Hi' and 1, 2, 3 is becasue you have `set @csvnmbr = @csvnmbr + 1` so you rebind value to old value + 1, hi is always the same, you just print twice

Comment: The clue is when you set `@sql` before loop it is fixed and won't change unless you explicitly use `SET @sql = 'new_value'`, try instead of print `SEECT @sql, @csvnmbr`

Comment: I understand well the function of the @csvnmbr, I was referring to the actual replacement of it by it's value in the sql string when I said that printing or executing the sql variable had set it. In CTEs a totally virtual table is created (as I am sure you are aware) so I was thinking that the sql string would be able to virtually replace the csvnmbr variable in the sql string for the purposes of the first pass of the loop and then there would be no need to set the sql string in the loop because it could again virtually replace the csvnmbr variable for the second pass of the loop...!

Comment: So can we assume that everything is clear and close this question :)

Comment: Yes all clear, good going :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because it is set once before loop starts. You need to set `@sql` inside loop:

```
DECLARE @csvnmbr  INT = 1
        ,@sql     NVARCHAR(MAX);

WHILE @csvnmbr < 4
BEGIN
   SET @sql = N'BULK INSERT #tablename FROM ''C:\TEMP\'' +
               CAST(@csvnmbr AS NVARCHAR(10)) + 
               '.csv'' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '','')';
   PRINT @sql;
   SET @csvnmbr += 1;
END
```

About your question why it needs to be inside loop:

```
declare @csvnmbr nvarchar(3)
declare @sql nvarchar(400)
set @csvnmbr = 1

/* At this point @sql if fixed string, during concatenation @csvnmbr was
   replaced by its actual value */
set @sql = 'BULK INSERT #tablename FROM ''C:\TEMP\'+@csvnmbr+'.csv''
            WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '','')'


while @csvnmbr < 4
begin
print @sql  /* Here sql will be always the same you need to set it again */
set @csvnmbr = @csvnmbr + 1
end
```

What you trying to achieve is passing string by reference. You can mimic it like this:

```
DECLARE @csvnmbr NVARCHAR(3) = '1'
        ,@sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = 
 N'BULK INSERT #tablename FROM ''C:\TEMP\@csvnmbr.csv'' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '','')';

WHILE @csvnmbr < 4
BEGIN
   /* Warning!!! This will execute code in @sql*/
   EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
           @sql,
           N'@csvnmbr nvarchar(3)',
           @cvnmbr;                  /* Will substitute @csvnmbr with passed value */

   SET @csvnmbr += 1;
END
```

Comment: @russ See my updated answer, I address your concerns about why it need to be in loop.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your statement inside the while loop

```
declare @csvnmbr nvarchar(3)
declare @sql nvarchar(400)
set @csvnmbr = 1

while @csvnmbr < 4
begin
 set @sql = 'BULK INSERT #tablename FROM ''C:\TEMP\'+@csvnmbr+'.csv''
            WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '','')'
print @sql
set @csvnmbr = @csvnmbr + 1
end
GO
```

the while loop iteration happens between the while loop condition begin and end blocks.

```
WHILE (Some Condition)   --<-- first the condition is checked
  BEGIN
                         --<-- if the while condition is evaluated to true
                            -- code between the BEGIN and END is executed
       -- it keeps getting executing until while condition returns false
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill @sql in each iteration:

```
DECLARE @csvnmbr NVARCHAR(3);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(400);
SET @csvnmbr = 1;

SET @sql = 'BULK INSERT #tablename FROM ''C:\TEMP\' + @csvnmbr + '.csv''
        WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '','')';

WHILE @csvnmbr < 4

BEGIN

    PRINT @sql;

    SET @csvnmbr = @csvnmbr + 1;

SET @sql = 'BULK INSERT #tablename FROM ''C:\TEMP\' + @csvnmbr + '.csv''
         WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '','')';    

END;

GO
```